# Calculate the time stamp of year

Tags: php

Given that I have `$num_years`, how can I add it to `Time()`  to get a time stamp `$num_years` hence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strtotime("+$num_years years")` will give you a timestamp `$num_years` years in the future.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
echo strtotime("now + $num_years years");
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're after?

```
$num_years = 5;
$future = strtotime("+{$num_years} years");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo strftime('%Y %a %d %m, %T', strtotime('+' . $num_years . ' years') );
```

Change `strfttime` format according your needs.
Check out `strtotime` man page http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 2):

Well if you looking for the timestamp for just that time then use `mktime`

```
mktime(0,0,0,0,0,$noOfYears);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php

Comment: won't that return 00:00 1st Jan $num_years hence?   If today is 1st Dec and I add two years, I want to see 1st Dec 2012

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want ?

```
//Example to add 1 year to a date object
$num_years = 1;

$currentDate = date("Y-m-d");// current date

//Display the current date
echo "Current Date: ".$currentDate."<br>";

//Add one year to current date
$dateOneYearAdded = strtotime(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($currentDate)) . " +$num_years years");
echo "Date After adding one year: ".date('l dS \o\f F Y', $dateOneYearAdded)."<br>";
```